# My custom icon not showing in opengl

Tags: c++, windows, icons, openframeworks

I am working on an application with openFrameworks. As far as I know you can only open a openGL window from openFrameworks, and somehow this window does not use the icon.ico I want. It is showing on the .exe file though and on the console window.

There is a couple of things I tried:

1. The console window was showing the icon correctly. It is setup in icon.rc as the main icon. I thought maybe the console window is opened first so the icon is assigned, and when the other window opens it doesn't assign my icon anymore. So I tried to get rid of the console window (I wont need it for release anyway) And I changed subsystem from console to windows. And changed main() to WINAPI WinMain(.... etc. But this doesn't solve my icon problem it is still not showing.
2. tried to change some stuff in resource.h and icon.rc but there was not much to change and nothing seemed to work.
3. Tried searching for functions in the openGL window settings from openFrameworks but you can only change the screen size and some other basic stuff.

Any idea why this screen is not showing my icon?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The window icon is unrelated to the application icon displayed in Explorer. It's also unrelated to OpenGL.

Comment: Show your `WinMain` function and/or `WM_CREATE` switch. There should be class registration somewhere, that's where you set `WNDCLASSEX::hIcon`. If that's not accessible, find the `HWND` window handle and send `WM_SETICON` message

Comment: Thanks guys I managed to fix it, I will post another answer how I did it, because code in this mini-markdown isn't looking pretty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it like this thanks to: Colonel Thirty Two and Barmak Shemirani!! Instead of using ofGetWin32Window() You can probably use a similar get window function if not working with openFrameworks :)

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofApp.h"
#include "../resource.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

    ofSetupOpenGL(1280, 720,OF_WINDOW); 

    HWND hwnd = ofGetWin32Window();  
    HICON hMyIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAIN_ICON));
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hMyIcon);

    ofRunApp(new ofApp());

}
```